# How to integrate endpoints with Instagram Graph API?

Tags: spring-mvc, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I want to set up a webhook using the Instagram Graph API. I've made my application in Spring ready. My application successfully validates requests in Verification Requests. After that I subscribed to mention objects in the App dashboard.

I have created two Instagram accounts for testing, one Instagram business account and the other representing people who following the first account. My test scenario uses the second account to send dummy posts that also mention the first account. I expect my application to receive a notification but after some testing, nothing happens.

How to integrate my Spring application with the Instagram Graph API application. Thank you.

Comment: I am in the exact same situation as you. I've setup webhook for mentions and using two accounts for testing. But I never receive any requests when I mention in a post. Did you have any progress? Anything useful to share?